# Find maximum of minimum for every window size in a given array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am having trouble understanding the example given below.
Given an integer array of size n, find the maximum of the minimum’s of every window size (length of a contiguous sub-array) in the array. Note that window size varies from 1 to n.

```
Input:  arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 50, 10, 70, 30}
Output:         70, 30, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10
```

First element in output indicates maximum of minimums of all 
windows of size 1.
Minimums of windows of size 1 are {10}, {20}, {30}, {50}, {10},
{70} and {30}.  Maximum of these minimums is 70

Second element in output indicates maximum of minimums of all 
windows of size 2.
Minimums of windows of size 2 are {10}, {20}, {30}, {10}, {10},
and {30}.  Maximum of these minimums is 30

My question is: why minimums of windows of size 2 are {10}, {20}, {30}, {10}, {10}, and {30}? Shouldn't windows of size 2 come from adding windows of size 1?

Comment: What is a "window size"?  This is critical to understanding the problem, and the term isn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "window" is a sequence of consecutive elements in the array.  Windows of size 1 are simply the individual array elements.  Windows of size 2 are consecutive pairs:

```
{10, 20}
     {20, 30}
         {30, 50}
             {50, 10}
                 {10, 70}
                     {70, 30}
```

The corresponding minima are 10, 20, 30, 10, 10, 30.  The maximum of these is 30.

When we get to size 3 ...

```
Window        min
10, 20, 30     10
20, 30, 50     20
30, 50, 10     10
50, 10, 70     10
10, 70, 30     10
           max 20
```

See how that works?

Comment: why does size 3 have max 20? shouldn't it be 70?

Comment: Nope.  Now that I've properly formatted my table, you can see why.

Comment: The term 'window size' is confusing, thanks for figuring this out, very helpful!

Comment: Great.  When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: the term *window (size)* is not that confusing in the realm of signal processing https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/9465

Comment: @Wolf: I think this would go better placed on the full question, right below my display of ignorance.  :-)

Comment: this was also meant as a response to Alpha's *The term 'window size' is confusing* -- I found your correction of the question a bit too much. this is all a bit confusing ... ;)